# Error while executing Mariadb update statement

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm using following update statement to update a row in a table of my database

```
update department
set budget = budget + 0.01
where dept_name = 'Physics';
```

However, running this code gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE university.update_budget_proc does not exist
```

I'm not able to make anything out of this error message. I have attached the screenshot of when I type the commands in terminal.

Also, to mention that I have never created any procedure 'update_budget_proc' which is mentioned in the error message. Does it really have anything to do with the update statement ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have an update trigger on that table? Is the trigger trying to call a procedure by that name?

Comment: `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'department'` to see the triggers for your table.

Comment: @billI_karwin thank you. I got the problem. There was actually a trigger that I had created before which was trying to call this procedure. May be later I had dropped this procedure which resulted in the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guess in the comments above turned out to be right.

The UPDATE was executing a trigger, which in turn had a reference to a stored procedure that no longer exists.